# When i uncheck Checkbox Next Checkbox get Selected after Scrolling ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Please help i am trying to do multiple checkbox selection in ListView.
I also tried/refer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100518/checkbox-auto-call-oncheckedchange-when-listview-scroll) & also [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343773/when-scrolling-custom-listview-the-checkbox-value-changes) but now i get new error, when i uncheck CheckBox next CheckBox get Selected after Scrolling ListView. I don't know what's wrong with my code, Please help me out.

```js
//Main ListView Class


 public View getViewByPosition(int position, ListView listView) {
  final int firstListItemPosition = closeMListView
    .getFirstVisiblePosition();
  final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition
    + closeMListView.getChildCount() - 1;

  if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition) {
   return closeMListView.getAdapter().getView(position, null,
     closeMListView);
  } else {
   final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
   return closeMListView.getChildAt(childIndex);
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
   long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("Inside onItemClick  position     " + position);
  System.out.println("Inside onItemClick  ckStatus     " + ckStatus.size());
  View vi = getViewByPosition(position, closeMListView);
  cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.ckHStatus);
  // cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
  // cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

  System.out.println("Inside onItemClick  ckStatus     "
    + (ckStatus.get(position) == true));
  if (ckStatus.get(position) == true) {
   ckStatus.add(position, false);
   cb.setChecked(false);
   ListViewAdapterForCloseM.mIds
     .remove(ListViewAdapterForCloseM.mId.get(position));
  } else {
   cb.setChecked(true);
   ckStatus.add(position, true);
   ListViewAdapterForCloseM.mIds
     .add(ListViewAdapterForCloseM.mId.get(position));
  }
 }
```

My Adapter Class is

```js
public class ListViewAdapterForCloseM extends BaseAdapter {
 Context mContext;
 MyAppDB helper;
 public static ArrayList<String> mId;
 ArrayList<String> vName, vMDate, mStatus;
 public static ArrayList<String> mIds;
 LayoutInflater inflater;
 ViewHolder holder;
 Cursor cr;
 View vi;
 int myPosition;

 public ListViewAdapterForCloseM(Context context,
   int listviewItemClosemeeting,
   List<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  System.out.println("Inside ListView AD  arrayList     "
    + arrayList.size());

  mContext = context;
  helper = new MyAppDB(mContext, MyAppDB.DB_NAME, null, 1);
  mId = new ArrayList<String>();
  vName = new ArrayList<String>();
  vMDate = new ArrayList<String>();
  mStatus = new ArrayList<String>();
  mIds = new ArrayList<String>();

  for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
   HashMap<String, String> content = new HashMap<String, String>();
   content = arrayList.get(i);
   mId.add(content.get("Id"));
   vName.add(content.get("vName"));
   vMDate.add(content.get("Date"));
   mStatus.add(content.get("status"));
  }
 }

 class ViewHolder {
  TextView tvVName, tvMDate, tvMStatus;
  CheckBox cb;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return mId.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return position;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return position;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  vi = convertView;
  holder = null;
  myPosition = position;

  System.out.println("Inside getView " + position);
  if (vi == null) {
   vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
     R.layout.listview_adapter_item, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.tvVName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvLvVName);
   holder.tvMDate = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvLvDate);
   holder.tvMStatus = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvLvStatus);
   holder.cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.ckHStatus);
   vi.setTag(R.id.ckHStatus, holder.cb);
   vi.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
  }

  System.out.println("Inside getView status     "
    + CloseM.ckStatus.get(position));
  holder.tvVName.setText(vName.get(position));
  holder.tvMDate.setText(vMDate.get(position));
  holder.tvMStatus.setText(mStatus.get(position));
  holder.cb.setChecked(CloseM.ckStatus.get(position));
  // holder.cb.setTag(holder);
  return vi;
 }
}
```

Comment: the code snippet functionality is for html / css / javascript.

Comment: @GottZ i don't know stackoverflow overall Please check code and try to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code

```
holder.cb.setChecked(CloseM.ckStatus.get(position));
```

inside getView of an adapter class,when ever you are scrolling listview getView method of adatper class will be called hence the checkbox is gettting selected.

you can make your checkbox selected either in LIstItem or some where else as per your need.

Comment: when i do that and select any checkbox like 0th position 4th, 8th, 12th... Checkbox gets selected authomatically.  @venkatesh

Comment: Inside LIstView onItemClick, when i check all item status are "false" but checkbox get's selected, how it is possible i don't understand?

Comment: then problem might be the if condition you have used for set checkbox is true,kinldy check the "ckStatus.get(position)" returns what..!

Comment: Actually i never check CheckBox status inside if, i create ArrayList<boolean>  which is full of false with equal size of listview and you know onItemClick().

(ckStatus.get(position) == true)   ArrayList<boolean> at position value.